# ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/tmp/react-native-packager-cache-02b2ace9b81fa119b172fdfd36d3a3b4e4156b70/cache'

Tags: android, caching, react-native, react-native-ios

while doing release build android react-native

```
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

the follwing error thrown at the end.

```
Loading dependency graph, done.

ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/tmp/react-native-packager-cache-02b2ace9b81fa119b172fdfd36d3a3b4e4156b70/cache'

:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I am using

```
"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "0.49.3",
```

Please guide

Answer (score 2):

try `./gradlew clean` and then `./gradlew assembleRelease` . It should work .

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following, and it worked for me,

1)Type **rm -rf ~./rncache** and hit enter.

2)watchman watch-del-all; npm start -- --reset-cache

3)Remove **node_modules** folder from your project.

4)Now run **npm install**

5)Finally **react-native run-android**

Hope it will work.